# SQL SSIS Script Task Using C# to Process All Rows

Tags: c#, ssis

In SSIS, I have a Script Task that takes in 10 rows of data, containing 6 values

```
- Row.WorkOrderID
- Row.WorkOrderProductID
- Row.BatchNo
- Row.OldQty
- Row.NewQty
```

I need extract all records that have the same `Row.WorkOrderID` and `Row.WorkOrderProductID`, but different `Row.NewQty` compared to `Row.OldQty`.

I'm aware that SSIS Script Task `ProcessInputRow` method processes row by row. In my case, can this only be done in `PostExecute` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using conditional splits to do the job and merge again if needed. Script task is only as a last option if something can't be done by the transforms that SSIS has, and because Script task process row by row it is slow for large data.
Check out the condition to use at conditional split:
[image]